# Setting environment variables for RStudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, environment-variables, rstudio, tmp

I am on Ubuntu 22.04. I am trying to create a new environment variable for R. In RStudio, I can see all the environment variables for R in RStudio terminal with the command:

```
printenv | grep ^R_
```

but the same doesn't work in a terminal outside of RStudio. I used

```
Sys.setenv(TMPDIR=/my/fav/path)
```

but it only persists for that R session. I tried using '.Renviron' file in my project folder as well but the attempt went in vain. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I haven't been able to set any environment variable myself yet. I can only see them through the 'printenv' command in the terminal or 'Sys.getenv()' in R console. I am not sure where they are coming from.

Comment: How are you launching RStudio? Where are you setting the environment variable? See also: https://askubuntu.com/q/1186076/9287

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am launching it via the app on Ubuntu. I haven't been able to set environment variables yet. But they only show up when I launch RStudio, and are not existent any other time. I cannot find if there is any file that is setting them whenever I launch RStudio.

Comment: Ah, right, I got it the wrong way round. Yes, these environment variables are set *by R* when it starts, and are populated from various sources (including `~/.REnviron`). They are not set outside of R. If you want them to be set you need to explicitly set them yourself, e.g. in your `.bashrc` file or equivalent (depending on your shell).

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you, setting the TMPDIR variable in '.Renviron' in my root folder updated my 'R_SESSION_TMPDIR' accordingly. I had the '.Renviron' in the wrong place.